# LINE.me backend for Errbot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, errbot, line.me

[LINE](http://line.me/) is a messaging system similar to WhatsApp. Is there anyone already written/writing a backend for Errbot?

A Python library to access LINE is located at [carpedm20.github.io](http://carpedm20.github.io/line/index.html).